# How to get the "Proportion Var" line from PCA output using principal from package psych?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to get the the "Proportion Var" line like object or vector from "pca $ loadings" below, to use its values in the PCA graphic.

I did the following:

```
library(psych)  

data(iris)

pca <- principal(iris[1:4],nfactors = 2,rotate="varimax",scores=TRUE)

pca$loadings
```

How should I get the proportional var?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to compute manually, but first you need to extract all factors (e.g., all axes)

You should specify the `nfactors` as the number of variables that you have, which in your example is 4. So it should be like like this:

```
pca <- principal(iris[1:4],nfactors = 4,rotate="varimax",scores=TRUE)
```

Then, extract the `pca$loadings` after which you can compute the proportional variance by getting the sum of squared loadings per component (RC in this case) and divide them by the total sum squared loadings, which you can do by this:

```
colSums(pca$loadings[ , ]^2)/sum(pca$loadings[ , ]^2)
```

This should give you the same information as the proportion variance in the `pca$loadings`, albeit for all the components (RC1 to RC4 in this case).